# Foursquare api json not appearing in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, json, api, internet-explorer, foursquare

The code below works in every browser except for IE (including IE9 on Windows 7). Please help, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KBJwh/

## -- Update --

Based on some feedback I have updated the code using `var` and added an alert with a super simple call to the venue's name. I am still unable to view the data from the JSON on IE.

New Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZachSchneider/KBJwh/4/

Thank you in advance!

```
// 4sq API JSON
    var jsonURL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4a9fec80f964a520923d20e3?client_id=FPD2H4NAKX3ABYPEGR2LAMSWV41HC3GSWAEDOCVR00ZDS3LL&client_secret=FCV2G2P3MXZQE2HQYCLHPTMFR03ARE4MWLM34KOX4MXIKCX4&v=20130114";

    // Now let us go and grab that mayor from the API 
    jQuery.getJSON(jsonURL, function (data) {

        // Test Case
            jQuery.each(data.response, function(index, nm){
                    alert(nm.name);
            });

        // Looking through the JSON 
        jQuery.each(data.response.venue.mayor.user, function (i, item) {

            // Neededed 4sq variables 
            var photo = data.response.venue.mayor.user.photo.suffix,
            firstName = data.response.venue.mayor.user.firstName,
            lastName = data.response.venue.mayor.user.lastName,
            checkins = data.response.venue.mayor.count;

            // Content to append into HTML 
            currentMayor = '<img src="https://is1.4sqi.net/userpix_thumbs/' + photo + '"  width="55" height="55" /><p>Congrats, <span class="currentMayor">' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' ' + checkins + '</span> check-ins in the last 60 days</p>';
        });

        jQuery(currentMayor).prependTo("#myDIV");
    });
```

Comment: You need to be much more specific than "doesn't work in IE". Do you get any error messages at all in the IE console?

One thing you should be doing is using the `var` keyword when declaring variables. I don't know if that is causing the problem but it's a good practice to get into anyway.

Comment: @JackFranklin I added `alert()` for testing in IE and the it looks that it was breaking at the `.getJSON()` I also tried using `var` [example here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBJwh/1/) but that didn't look to fix the issue. When you look at this in IE it doesn't prepend the variable `currentMayor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the `.ajax()` method which offers fail and success attributes.

```
// 4sq API JSON
    var jsonURL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4a9fec80f964a520923d20e3?client_id=FPD2H4NAKX3ABYPEGR2LAMSWV41HC3GSWAEDOCVR00ZDS3LL&client_secret=FCV2G2P3MXZQE2HQYCLHPTMFR03ARE4MWLM34KOX4MXIKCX4&v=20130114";
var request = jQuery.ajax({
    url: jsonURL,
    context: document.body
});
// Yay! JSON is working 
request.success(function () {
    // Now let us go and grab that mayor from the API 
    jQuery.getJSON(jsonURL, function (data) {

        // Looking through the JSON 
        jQuery.each(data.response.venue.mayor.user, function (i, item) {

            // Neededed 4sq variables 
            var photo = data.response.venue.mayor.user.photo.suffix,
                firstName = data.response.venue.mayor.user.firstName,
                lastName = data.response.venue.mayor.user.lastName,
                checkins = data.response.venue.mayor.count;


            // Content to append into HTML 
            currentMayor = '<img src="https://is1.4sqi.net/userpix_thumbs/' + photo + '"  width="55" height="55" /><p>Congrats, <span class="currentMayor">' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' ' + checkins + '</span> check-ins in the last 60 days</p>';
        });
        jQuery(currentMayor).prependTo("#myDIV");
    });
});
// Foursquare failed or you are just using IE 
request.fail(function () {
    jQuery("<div>placeholder copy for IE or broken API</div>").prependTo("#myDIV");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `&callback=?` to the end of your URL